# Substring the text value of select2 in Yii2

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2

I am trying to trim the text value of my select2field. In console.log it works, but when I am trying to put it in select2 it does not trimmed the string.it still returned the whole string.

here is my code:

```
   $(".myselect2field").on("change",function(){
     var item_field = $(".myselect2field").select2("data"); //get the text value
     var item_field_length = item_field[0].text.length; // get the length of text value
       if(item_field_length > 30){
            console.log(item_field[0].text.substring(0,25));
            console.log(item_field_length);
        //  $(".myselect2field").val($(".appfield option:contains(item_field)").val(item_field[0].toString().substring(0,25))).change();
           $(".myselect2field").val(item_field[0].text.substring(0,25));

       }

 });
```

Comment: You should use the default events provided by select2 plugin and use then via `pluginOptions` option of select2 like `'pluginOptions'=>["change" => "function() { log('change'); }",]`

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed triming it, but you are not refreshing your select2 so the value that is shown it is still the old value.

Just add `trigger("change")` after you set the new trimmed value:

```
$(".myselect2field").val(item_field[0].text.substring(0,25)).trigger("change");
```

Comment: Hello! I tried your code but iit returns Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined


it gives that error to this part
  var item_field_length = item_field[0].text.length; // get the length of text value

Comment: @Ramzkie then the problem is that item_field[0] is empty, check the values of item_field with `console.log(item_field)`